# What is the Sub limit in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have very large pieces of information, e.g.:

''''''''''120/240V 1Ø 3W, Electrical Metallic Tubing, Copper Conductor Variables''''''''''

```
If Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "80A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "80A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''80A @ 125% & 80A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''100A & 100A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "1 Set(s) of 3 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 1 1/4in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "160A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "80A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''160A @ 125% & 160A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''200A & 100A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "1 Set(s) of 2 - #3/0 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "160A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "160A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''160A @ 125% & 160A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''200A & 200A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "1 Set(s) of 3 - #3/0 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "320A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "80A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''320A @ 125% & 80A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''400A & 100A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "1 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "320A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "160A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''320A @ 125% & 160A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''400A & 200A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "1 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3/0 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "320A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "320A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''320A @ 125% & 320A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''400A & 400A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "1 Set(s) of 3 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "480A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "80A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''480A @ 125% & 80A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''600A & 100A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "2 Set(s) of 2 - #350 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "480A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "160A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''480A @ 125% & 160A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''600A & 200A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "2 Set(s) of 2 - #350 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "480A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "320A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''480A @ 125% & 320A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''600A & 400A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "2 Set(s) of 2 - #350 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3/0 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "480A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "480A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''480A @ 125% & 480A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''600A & 600A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "2 Set(s) of 3 - #350 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "640A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "80A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''640A @ 125% & 80A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''800A & 100A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "2 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "640A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "160A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''640A @ 125% & 160A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''800A & 200A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "2 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "640A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "320A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''640A @ 125% & 320A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''800A & 400A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "2 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3/0 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "640A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "480A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''640A @ 125% & 480A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''800A & 600A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "2 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #350 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "640A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "640A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''640A @ 125% & 640A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''800A & 800A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "2 Set(s) of 3 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "960A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "80A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''960A @ 125% & 80A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''1200A & 100A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "3 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "960A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "160A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''960A @ 125% & 160A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''1200A & 200A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "3 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "960A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "320A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''960A @ 125% & 320A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''1200A & 400A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "3 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #1/0 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "960A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "480A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''960A @ 125% & 480A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''1200A & 600A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "3 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3/0 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "960A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "640A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''960A @ 125% & 640A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''1200A & 800A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "3 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #300 MCM THHN/THWNN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "960A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "960A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''960A @ 125% & 960A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''1200A & 1200A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "3 Set(s) of 3 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1280A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "80A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1280A @ 125% & 80A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''1600A & 100A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "4 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1280A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "160A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1280A @ 125% & 160A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''1600A & 200A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "4 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1280A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "320A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1280A @ 125% & 320A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''1600A & 400A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "4 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1280A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "480A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1280A @ 125% & 480A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''1600A & 600A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "4 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #1/0 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1280A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "640A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1280A @ 125% & 640A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''1600A & 800A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "4 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3/0 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1280A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "960A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1280A @ 125% & 960A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''1600A & 1200A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "4 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #350 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1280A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "1280A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1280A @ 125% & 1280A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''1600A & 1600A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "4 Set(s) of 3 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1600A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "80A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1600A @ 125% & 80A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2000A & 100A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "5 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1600A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "160A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1600A @ 125% & 160A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2000A & 200A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "5 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1600A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "320A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1600A @ 125% & 320A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2000A & 400A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "5 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1600A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "480A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1600A @ 125% & 480A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2000A & 600A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "5 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #1 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1600A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "640A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1600A @ 125% & 640A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2000A & 800A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "5 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #2/0 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1600A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "960A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1600A @ 125% & 960A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2000A & 1200A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "5 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #250 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1600A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "1280A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1600A @ 125% & 1280A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2000A & 1600A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "5 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #400 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1600A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "1600A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1600A @ 125% & 1600A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2000A & 2000A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "5 Set(s) of 3 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1920A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "80A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1920A @ 125% & 80A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2400A & 100A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "6 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1920A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "160A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1920A @ 125% & 160A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2400A & 200A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "6 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1920A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "320A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1920A @ 125% & 320A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2400A & 400A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "6 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1920A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "480A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1920A @ 125% & 480A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2400A & 600A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "6 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1920A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "640A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1920A @ 125% & 640A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2400A & 800A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "6 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #1/0 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1920A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "960A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1920A @ 125% & 960A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2400A & 1200A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "6 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3/0 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1920A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "1280A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1920A @ 125% & 1280A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2400A & 1600A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "6 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #300 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1920A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "1600A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1920A @ 125% & 1600A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2400A & 2000A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "6 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #400 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "1920A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "1920A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''1920A @ 125% & 1920A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2400A & 2400A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "6 Set(s) of 3 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "2240A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "80A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''2240A @ 125% & 80A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2800A & 100A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "7 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "2240A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "160A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''2240A @ 125% & 160A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2800A & 200A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "7 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "2240A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "320A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''2240A @ 125% & 320A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2800A & 400A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "7 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "2240A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "480A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''2240A @ 125% & 480A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2800A & 600A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "7 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "2240A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "640A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''2240A @ 125% & 640A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2800A & 800A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "7 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #2 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "2240A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "960A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''2240A @ 125% & 960A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2800A & 1200A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "7 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #2/0 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "2240A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "1280A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''2240A @ 125% & 1280A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2800A & 1600A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "7 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #4/0 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "2240A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "1600A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''2240A @ 125% & 1600A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2800A & 2000A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "7 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #300 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

ElseIf Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(12, 7) = "2240A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "1920A @ 125%" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then
    '''''2240A @ 125% & 1920A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''2800A & 2400A'''''
  Cells(7, 7) = "7 Set(s) of 2 - #600 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #500 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 3 1/2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."
```

I have 144 of these very large blocks that I need excel to sort through to return the different results.

Is there a limit on sub-routines?

I would need at least 144..

Thank you!

Dan C.

Comment: No hard limit that i have ever heard of.  Having said that, there is always a limit in the form of a file will get to big or things will get to slow. But you should be fine at 144.

Comment: Surely there's a better way to write your sub than near-identical code pasted in giant blocks... have you tried to determine whether you can simply use some loops to iterate through your various tests?

Comment: It looks like you have a large number of combinations to process and sort through in order to reach a single conclusion (the value in `Cell(7,7)`). It would probably help if you built a logic table that specified how each field combines, then a (relatively) simpler VBA loop to run through the table to reach your conclusion. With this method, you only have to change your logic table to update/change/fix/add-new-combinations without having to change at least 144 different logic blocks.

Comment: "[64K of compiled code in a single procedure](http://excel.tips.net/T003174_Maximum_Length_Limit_for_a_Macro.html)"

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you can improve this. First of all, you can nest the `If` statements to factor out the parts that appear on each line:

```
If Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And _
    Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And _
    Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then

    If Cells(12, 7) = "80A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "80A @ 125%" Then
        '''''80A @ 125% & 80A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''100A & 100A'''''
      Cells(7, 7) = "1 Set(s) of 3 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 1 1/4in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."

    ElseIf Cells(12, 7) = "160A @ 125%" And Cells(13, 7) = "80A @ 125%" Then
        '''''160A @ 125% & 160A @ 125%'''''1st Set = Ungrounded Conductor(s); 2nd Set = Grounded Conductor.'''''200A & 100A'''''
      Cells(7, 7) = "1 Set(s) of 2 - #3/0 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; & 1 - #3 MCM THHN/THWN cu.; in 2in. Electrical Metallic Tubing(E.M.T.)."
...
End If
```

However, since you are working in Excel, you can build a look-up table like this to dramatically simplify your code:

[image]

The lookup table moves the cumbersome logic out of the code to where it can be easily read and updated. The code is then reduced to this:

```
If Cells(8, 2) = "X" And Cells(9, 9) = "120/240V 1Ø 3W:" And _
    Cells(11, 9) = "Electrical Metallic Tubing" And _
    Cells(12, 9) = "Copper Conductor(s)" And Cells(90, 1) = "x" Then

    Worksheets("Lookup").Range("A2") = Cells(12, 7)
    Worksheets("Lookup").Range("B2") = Cells(13, 7)
    Application.Calculate
    Cells(7, 7) = Worksheets("Lookup").Range("C2")

End If
```

Name the new sheet "Lookup" and put this formula in cell C2: `=INDEX($C$4:$C$58,MATCH(A2,IF($B$4:$B$58=B2,$A$4:$A$58),0))` (be sure to enter as an array formula by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter rather than just Enter).